# Find the order of a group element

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Find the order of an element 
$\left(\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
    5 & 3 & 4 & 2 & 6 & 1 
  \end{smallmatrix}\bigr),b\right)$ 
 
 
in the direct product G x H where G is the symmetric group $S_6$ and H is the Klein-4-group. 
 
 
What I did:
 
 
A corollary from Lagrange's Theorem tells us that the order of an element divides an order of a group.  I will denote it as $ |g|$ divides $|G|$.
 
  The order of $ |H|=4,|G|=6!=720$. 
 
 
 Now I have no idea of the possible next step.

Comment: Written as the product of disjoint cycles, the permutation you list is $(156)(234)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

Decompose the permutation in $S_6$ as  a product of disjoint cycles. The order of a cycle is its length, and the order of a product of disjoint cycles is the l.c.m. of the orders of its cycle components. Finally, the order of $(\sigma, b)$ is the l.c.m. of the orders of $\sigma$ and $b$.